# Json Include Null values for specific children

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the below class types

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
class Response {
    @JsonProperty("employee")
    private Employee employee;

    @JsonProperty("orders")
    private Orders orders;

}
```

My Orders looks like below

```
class Orders {
private ShippingInfo shippingInfo;
private String ordersCount;
}
```

My ShippingInfo looks like

```
class ShippingInfo {
private String shipmentType;
private String shipmentQuantity;
}
```

Now when displaying the Response Json I wanted the all the members of class `ShippingInfo` to show the null values too.

I know we can use @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS) but I wanted to do it only for the ShippingInfo and not for the other classes like Orders and Employees.

Comment: Than add it only at shippinginfo

Comment: @Jens So then @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY) on the Response class wont remove them again?

Comment: Try it out. I am not sure